# Removing the warning message "on-variable type argument Int in type ... is unchecked" with Scala

Tags: scala, function, warnings

I have a function that calculate the tuple values only when the input is a tuple of four integers.

```
def add(v:Any) = {
    if (v.isInstanceOf[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]) {
        val v2 = v.asInstanceOf[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]
        println(v2._1 + v2._2 + v2._3 + v2._4)
    } else {
        println("NOP")
    }
}

object Main extends App {
    add((1,1,1,1))
    add((1,2))
}

Main.main(args)
```

It's working, but I got a warning of "non-variable type argument ... is unchekced" warning.

```
warning: non-variable type argument Int in type (Int, Int, Int, Int) is 
unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
if (v.isInstanceOf[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]) {
```

Why this error, and what might be the best way to remove this warning message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually need to check that the argument is a tuple of four `Int`s, the correct way to do this is to check each component:

```
def add(v: Any) = v match {
  case (i1: Int, i2: Int, i3: Int, i4: Int) =>
    println(i1 + i2 + i3 + i4)
  case _ =>
    println("NOP")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by `type erasure` in compile time, you can resolve it by [TypeTag](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def add[T](v:T)(implicit t: TypeTag[T]) = {
    if ( t.tpe =:= typeOf[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]) {
        val v2 = v.asInstanceOf[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]
        println(v2._1 + v2._2 + v2._3 + v2._4)
    } else {
        println("NOP")
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually have the desired behavior, it only works when the _static_ type of the argument is `(Int, Int, Int, Int)`. E.g. it won't work if called on the return value of a function returning `Any`.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `instanceOf`s with pattern matching and suppress the warning with `@unchecked`

```
def add(v: Any) = v match {
  case t: (Int, Int, Int, Int) @unchecked =>
    println(t._1 + t._2 + t._3 + t._4)
  case _ =>
    println("NOP")
}
```

if you pass a `Tuple4` that is not `(Int, Int, Int, Int)` you will get a `ClassCastException`

Error clearly says that generic types of tuple will be removed due to type erasure and hence compiler can't assure that this will work in runtime, it will only see if `Tuple4` was passed, not what it contains.

The solution I presented would cause you trouble if it is possible that the function would be called with other than `(Int, Int, Int, Int)` `Tuple4`, and then you should proceed with `TypeTag`s, otherways it just looks so much cleaner and doesn't need reflection.

Comment: IMO this is a better choice as it's cleaner and more idiomatic.